# How to make my Flex box sidebar go full screen when i resize the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have this Flex box and when i resize the page on mobile mode, i want to see the sidebar to go full screen and the footer to disappear.

Is there any way to make my sidebar to occupy the whole page only when i resize the window to mobile-mode?

I could not find anything relative to my question and it took me hours and hours to find a solution for this but i can not find anything...

Thank you guys in advance!

```
This is the CSS and below is the HTML:
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Nunito:300,300,700');
body {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    background: #EFF1F7;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.content {
    grid-area: content;
    
}
.sidebar{
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(249,107,142,1), rgba(218,103,230,1), rgba(130,125,253,1));
    justify-content: center;   
}
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background: white;
}
.container {
    font-size: 1em; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "sidebar"
    "content" 
    "footer"; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 130px 800px 250px;
}
.content,
.sidebar,
.footer {
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

nav li a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

nav li a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}



.action-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #867bfb;
    padding: 0.5em 2em;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 1em 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.action-btn:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 50px rgba(188,197,216,1);
}

footer ul {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

footer ul li {
    list-style: none;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
footer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c1c6ce;
}
svg {
    width: 40%;
}

footer p{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

@media (min-width: 1040px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-areas: "sidebar content" "sidebar footer"; 
        grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .sidebar {
        background: linear-gradient(
            rgba(249,107,142,1),
            rgba(218,103,230,1),
            rgba(130,125,254,1));
            padding-top: 3em;
            
    }
   
    footer ul {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2em 0;
    }
    svg {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="GalGadot.jpg" style="width: 120px; height: 80px; border-radius: 50%;"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saved</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
       
        <div class="footer">
            <footer>
                <ul> <!--instagram SVG icon-->
                    <li><a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 39 32.481"><defs><style>.a{fill:#98a0ad;}</style></defs><path class= "a" d="M17.25 7.288v1.269c0 .297-.241.539-.538.539h-1.269c-.299 0-.538-.242-.538-.539v-1.269c0-.297.239-.538.538-.538h1.269c.297 0 .538.241.538.538zm-5.25 7.403c1.486 0 2.693-1.205 2.693-2.692s-1.207-2.69-2.693-2.69c-1.487 0-2.691 1.204-2.691 2.691s1.204 2.691 2.691 2.691zm4.261-3.291c.028.196.046.396.046.599 0 2.38-1.928 4.308-4.307 4.308s-4.307-1.928-4.307-4.307c0-.204.018-.403.046-.599.027-.194.066-.383.118-.567h-1.107v5.879c0 .297.241.538.538.538h9.424c.297 0 .538-.241.538-.538v-5.879h-1.107c.05.184.09.373.118.566zm7.739.6c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12s-12-5.373-12-12 5.373-12 12-12 12 5.373 12 12zm-5-5.385c0-.892-.723-1.615-1.615-1.615h-10.77c-.892 0-1.615.723-1.615 1.615v10.769c0 .893.723 1.616 1.615 1.616h10.77c.892 0 1.615-.723 1.615-1.616v-10.769z"/></svg><p>3K</p></a></li>

                    <!--facebook SVG icon-->

                    <li><a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 39 32.481"><defs><style>.a{fill:#98a0ad;}</style>
                    </defs><path class="a" d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm3 8h-1.35c-.538 0-.65.221-.65.778v1.222h2l-.209 2h-1.791v7h-3v-7h-2v-2h2v-2.308c0-1.769.931-2.692 3.029-2.692h1.971v3z"/></svg><p>10K</p></a></li>

                    <!--twitter SVG icon-->
                    <li><a href="#"><svg  viewBox="0 0 39 32.481"><defs><style>.a{fill:#98a0ad;}.b{clip-path:url(#a);}</style><clipPath id="a"><rect class="a" width="39.337" height="33.328"></rect></clipPath></defs><g class="b"><path class="a" d="M23.643 4.937c-.835.37-1.732.62-2.675.733a4.67 4.67 0 0 0 2.048-2.578 9.3 9.3 0 0 1-2.958 1.13 4.66 4.66 0 0 0-7.938 4.25 13.229 13.229 0 0 1-9.602-4.868c-.4.69-.63 1.49-.63 2.342A4.66 4.66 0 0 0 3.96 9.824a4.647 4.647 0 0 1-2.11-.583v.06a4.66 4.66 0 0 0 3.737 4.568 4.692 4.692 0 0 1-2.104.08 4.661 4.661 0 0 0 4.352 3.234 9.348 9.348 0 0 1-5.786 1.995 9.5 9.5 0 0 1-1.112-.065 13.175 13.175 0 0 0 7.14 2.093c8.57 0 13.255-7.098 13.255-13.254 0-.2-.005-.402-.014-.602a9.47 9.47 0 0 0 2.323-2.41z"></path></g></svg><p>5.7K</p></a></li>

                        <!--Linkedin SVG icon-->
                    <li><a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 39 32.481"><defs><style>.a{fill:#98a0ad;}</style>
                    </defs><path class="a" d="M12 0c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-2 16h-2v-6h2v6zm-1-6.891c-.607 0-1.1-.496-1.1-1.109 0-.612.492-1.109 1.1-1.109s1.1.497 1.1 1.109c0 .613-.493 1.109-1.1 1.109zm8 6.891h-1.998v-2.861c0-1.881-2.002-1.722-2.002 0v2.861h-2v-6h2v1.093c.872-1.616 4-1.736 4 1.548v3.359z"/></svg><p>13.5K</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </div>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm seeing the sidebar taking up the full width on mobile. Are you talking about removing the image on mobile view so it's not in the way? To get rid of the footer on mobile view set it to `display: none` and then in a media query set it to `display: flex`, that should work.

Comment: I mean the full width of the whole window, from top to bottom...

Comment: Try setting the .sidebar element to `height: 100%`. Then in the media query set it to something like 10em. This should get it to take up the whole screen on mobile and only the top of the screen on larger screens.

Comment: What about `height: 100vh`?

Comment: @Nick Kinlen this really worked!!! Thanks a lot man!!

Comment: Tico, Anyway to close this Q? (The answer is 100VH).

Answer (score 1):

You could simple write a `@media` query to make `.sidebar { width: 100%}`
and `.footer { display: none }`